# Software Updater and sudo apt-get update

Tags: 18.04, update-manager

After installing software with Software Updater running

> sudo apt-get update

shouldn't return any hits right? This isn't the case on my system, I've installed some updates which "popped up" including security updates, but 3 days after when I run the above there are almost 30 hits (package list updates). So, this makes me wonder - does SU always run the update command before the upgrade one?

Comment: @user535733, I have one question. If this is indeed the "issue" - phased update (which is fine with me) then me running apt-get update, does it means that those updated will be installed in the next batch by the SU GUI or the SU will still follow the phased update schedule percent thing?

Comment: @mature, thanks for the link, it turns out the phased updated are mentioned there as well.

Comment: SU will always use schedule-percent-thing phased updates.

Comment: @user535733, thanks, how do you propose for me to close that one, is it going to be helpful for others? If yes then maybe you can post an answer, if not I can delete the question.

Comment: Folks with high-enough reputation will mark it as a duplicate soon enough.

Comment: Cool, thanks both for your help! Ah and I do have a button to accept the duplicate.. :)